# How to load .rtf files in webview?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I want to load rtf files with webview using raw folder. Below is my code;

```
 val urlWebView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)
 readTextFromResource(R.raw.lettemp_369)?.let { urlWebView.loadData(it, "text/rtf", "utf-8") };
```

Below is function;

```
private fun readTextFromResource(resourceID: Int): String? {
val raw: InputStream = resources.openRawResource(resourceID)
val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
var i: Int
try {
    i = raw.read()
    while (i != -1) {
        stream.write(i)
        i = raw.read()
    }
    raw.close()
} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
return stream.toString()
}
```

Comment: And? How does it go? Any problems? Any questions?

Comment: This loads nothing in webview. I have one rtf document in raw folder and I want to load this with webview plz help @blackapps

Comment: Do you think a webview can display a .rtf document? Did you ever see such?

Comment: No, but pdf files can be load with webview.

Comment: No. A webview cannot display a .pdf file.

Comment: https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-open-a-pdf-file-in-android-programmatically#:~:text=Opening%20a%20PDF%20file%20in%20Android%20using%20WebView&text=All%20you%20need%20to%20do%20is%20just%20put%20WebView%20in,loadUrl()%20function.&text=Now%2C%20run%20the%20application%20on,be%20displayed%20on%20the%20screen.

Comment: click on above link @blackapps

Comment: They mislead you. They do not load a .pdf document into their webview (as a webview cannot display a .pdf file) but use loadUrl for a google service to convert a pdf document (bihind an url) to html. The html is then displayed by the webview. A really shamefull tutorial.

Comment: So, how can I load rtf files in application without using external app. Do you have any idea @blackapps?

Comment: I think there is some rtf viewer library. Dont know where. Github?  Please google.

Comment: Can you guide me how to load rtf content with textview @blackapps?